# TypeError: Cannot find function testFunction in object

Tags: javascript

I have written a test function that sits inside my object, but cannot seem to access the function. What am I doing wrong? I mean I'm sure the code I've written is horrible, but specifically what is causing the error?:

```
function player(){

this.green=0;

  function testFunction(){
    this.green=99;
  };  
};
```

The player object is created in the game object:

```
function game(numPlayers){

  this.playerArray=[];

  switch(numPlayers){
  case 2:
    this.player1=new player();
    this.player2=new player();
    this.playerArray.push(this.player1,this.player2);
  break;
  case 3:
    this.player1=new player();
    this.player2=new player();
    this.player3=new player();
    this.playerArray.push(this.player1,this.player2,this.player3);
  break;
  case 4:
    this.player1=new player();
    this.player2=new player();
    this.player3=new player();
    this.player4=new player();
    this.playerArray.push(this.player1,this.player2,this.player3,this.player4);
  break;
  };

};
```

When I run:

```
var TE=new game(2);
TE.player1.testFunction();   <---
Logger.log(TE.player1.green);
```

I get the error in the subject line.

Comment: Why would testFunction be chainable, it's just a regular function ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define testFunction as a member of the player object:

```
function player(){

  this.green=0;

  this.testFunction = function(){
    this.green=99;
  };  
};
```

notice the "this.testFunction = function() ..."

Answer (score 0):

specifically:

you haven't exposed test function to be able to call it from outside.

do it like this:

```
function player(){

this.green=0;

  this.testFunction = function(){
    this.green=99;
  };
};
```

A better approach would be:

```
function Player(){ // capitalize class name

    this.green=0;

};

Player.prototype.testFunction = function( num ){
    this.green = num || 99;
}
```

by doing it this way all of your instances of player class doesn't need to have testFunction as there property instead there parent, there prototype will have this property which will be exposed by prototypal inheritance.